# How to use whats app developer api to send message to customer

Tags: node.js, chat, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have seen when I booked tickets in redbus or bookmyshow app. I will get a message in whats app also,I am developing an application when the user is done with booking tickets I need to send the tickets to their whats app number.

I have checked and created an account in nexmo. But I don't know how to send a message to whats app number.

Please help me to send whats app message using nodejs,
Thanks

Comment: So you want to use Nexmo's API? You'll probably have to ask them for documentation, the API endpoint and access credentials if you don't have them already.

Comment: anything is fine for me,I just need to send tickets to customer whats app number.That sould be licenced from whats app.Using nodejs,